# How do I manage a stream in a stateful widget

Tags: flutter

I'm working a daily routine app.  I use Provider to maintain the state of the app.

```
final routinesstate = Provider.of<RoutinesState>(context);
```

I have a Dashboard page in my app.  The Dashboard is a stateful widget, and contains a list of ActiveRoutineWidgets.

```
class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {
  List<Widget> activeroutineWidgets = List.empty(growable: true);
```

In its didChangeDependencies function the Dashboard populates the list of ActiveRoutineWidget stateful widgets, for display in the build function.

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    print('DashboardPageState didChangeDependencies');
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    buildActiveWidgetList(context);
  }

void buildActiveWidgetList(context) {
    final routinesstate = Provider.of<RoutinesState>(context, listen: false);
    List<int> activeRoutines = routinesstate.getactiveRoutines();

    activeroutineWidgets.clear();

    for (var i = 0; i < activeRoutines.length; i++) {
      if (activeroutineWidgets.length < 4) {
        activeroutineWidgets.add(ActiveRoutineWidget(
            activewidgetindex: i, routineindex: activeRoutines[i]));
        print('adding ActiveRoutineWidget to list.  widget index $i');
      }
    }
  }
```

The ActiveRoutineWidget listens to a broadcast stream of messages from a Apple Watch.

```
class _ActiveRoutineWidgetState extends State<ActiveRoutineWidget> {

StreamSubscription? watchmessageSubscription = null;


@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    print('ActiveRoutineWidget initState...');

     watchmessageSubscription = watchstate.receivedmessageStream.listen((message) async {});
   }

@override
  void dispose() {
    if (watchmessageSubscription != null)
      watchmessageSubscription!.cancel();
    print('ActiveRoutineWidget dispose');
    super.dispose();
  }
```

The first time the dashboard page is displayed it seems to work correctly.  However the next time the page is displayed, I am gettin duplicate ActiveRoutineWidgets, and therefore the stream is handling each message multiple times.

```
flutter: DashboardPageState initState
flutter: DashboardPageState didChangeDependencies
flutter: adding ActiveRoutineWidget to list.  widget index 0
flutter: ActiveRoutineWidget initState...
flutter: ActiveRoutineWidget didChangeDependencies
flutter: DashboardPageState didChangeDependencies
flutter: adding ActiveRoutineWidget to list.  widget index 0
flutter: ActiveRoutineWidget initState...
flutter: ActiveRoutineWidget didChangeDependencies
flutter: DashboardPageState didChangeDependencies
flutter: adding ActiveRoutineWidget to list.  widget index 0
flutter: ActiveRoutineWidget initState...
flutter: ActiveRoutineWidget didChangeDependencies
```

There is something fundamental about the widget lifecycle that I do not understand.

In buildActiveWidgetList, the first thing it does is clear the list of ActiveRoutineWidgets, and then re-populates the list based on app state.

When the list is cleared, shouldn't the dispose function of each ActiveRoutineWidget get called so that it can cancel its stream subscription?  Thats not happening, and I don't understand why.

Comment: where do you update the state?

Comment: State is updated by calling notifyListeners from my ChangeNotifier class